# show mongoDB database data in react component

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, express, components

How can I show data from nomgoDB database back in html with react component?
Should I create new component or use ejs file for example?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework? Express, Sails or Meteor?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Express

Comment: Ok, so what do you have already?